# Finding matching datasets in two separate spreadsheets (Excel/Pages)

Tags: excel, dataset, spreadsheet

Using Pages (or Excel) I'd like to do the following:

I have a list of around 150 order numbers in one spreadsheet (A).

In another spreadsheet (B) I have a database of all customers (thousands) including their order numbers and their email addresses.

I need to find a way to match the order numbers in (A) with the associated email addresses in (B), i.e. I need a list of all email addresses of the orders in list (A).

I'm not very good at Excel/Pages. Does anyone have an easy solution for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common `=VLOOKUP` scenario. Without knowing more about the specific details of what you need it's difficult to write something for you.

As you say you're not very experienced I would recommend using the Insert Function Wizard to put something together, have a look at this guide on how to create a vlookup formula through the wizard: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel/

Comment: Thanks so much! I've had a quick read through this and I can certainly see how this function could help, but I'm still struggling to apply it to my exact scenario. May I give you some more info? Spreadsheet 1 contains only one column with the selection of order IDs I need to find email addresses for, spreadsheet 2 contains column A with all order IDs (thousands) and column B with their associated email addresses. What I need to do is find the associated email addresses of the orders in spreadsheet 1.